# I get 'desktop.ini' answer when I try to "ls" in git bash

Tags: shell, git-bash

I am trying to access files in a directory (Desktop, Downloads, etc.) using Git Bash but I am only getting "desktop.ini" as respond. How do I see the files in Desktop using "ls"?

For example:

```
$ ls Desktop
desktop.ini
```

'ls'' output is this:

```
'3D Objects'/
 AppData/
'Application Data'@
 Contacts/
 Cookies@
 Desktop/
 Documents/
 Downloads/
 Favorites/
 IntelGraphicsProfiles/
 Links/
'Local Settings'@
 MicrosoftEdgeBackups/
 Music/
'My Documents'@
 NetHood@
 NTUSER.DAT
 ntuser.dat.LOG1
 ntuser.dat.LOG2
 NTUSER.DAT{04b8b7d3-5844-11e8-938c-9e5863255973}.TM.blf
 NTUSER.DAT{04b8b7d3-5844-11e8-938c-9e5863255973}.TMContainer00000000000000000001.regtrans-ms
 NTUSER.DAT{04b8b7d3-5844-11e8-938c-9e5863255973}.TMContainer00000000000000000002.regtrans-ms
 ntuser.ini
 OneDrive/
 Pictures/
 PrintHood@
 Recent@
'Saved Games'/
 Searches/
 SendTo@
'Start Menu'@
 Templates@
 Videos/
```

Comment: And this is a problem how exactly?

Comment: Hi, sorry but I am a total beginner at command line. I am trying to access files in a directory (Desktop, Downloads, etc.) but I am only getting "desktop.ini" as the respond. How do I see the files in Desktop using "ls"?

Comment: After starting Git Bash, can you provide the output to the following commands (without the quotes): "pwd" (i.e. Print Working Directory) and "ls /" (i.e. LiSt files in the root directory)

Comment: Yes! I have updated my question with the 'pwd' and 'ls' commands when I first started Git Bash

Comment: As far as I can see, you are listing the `~/Desktop` folder, and it contains only one file...

Comment: Hi, yes that is the problem! My desktop has many files but whenever I 'ls' it, I only get "desktop.ini" as response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify the location of your desktop files.

In Windows Explorer, there is a "Desktop" entry underneath your computer, alongside "Documents", "Downloads", your hard drive(s), etc.

Right click on the "Desktop" entry and select "Properties".

In the "Properties" window select the "Location" tab.

Within the "Location" tab it will display the path to the filesystem location where your desktop files are stored. You can then navigate to that path within Git Bash to interact with the files from the CLI.

Comment: I got it! Thank you so much chuckx!